# How to ignore url querystring from cached urls when using workbox?

Tags: caching, fetch, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Is there a way to ignore query string "?screenSize=" from below registered route using workbox! If I can use regex how would i write it in below scenario? Basically, I am looking to match the cache no matter what is the screenSize querystring.

```
workboxSW.router.registerRoute('https://example.com/data/image?screenSize=980',
workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'mycache',
    cacheExpiration: {
        maxEntries: 50
    },
    cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}
})
);
```

After trying the cachedResponseWillBeUsed plugin:
I do not see the plugin is applied:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Update: As of Workbox v4.2.0, the new `cacheKeyWillBeUsed` lifecycle callback can help override the default cache key for both read and write operations: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/releases/tag/v4.2.0**

**Original response:**

You should be able to do this by writing a [`cachedResponseWillBeUsed` plugin](https://workboxjs.org/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-runtime-caching.RequestWrapper.html#.cachedResponseWillBeUsed) that you pass in when you configure the strategy:

```
// See https://workboxjs.org/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-runtime-caching.RequestWrapper.html#.cachedResponseWillBeUsed
const cachedResponseWillBeUsed = ({cache, request, cachedResponse}) => {
  // If there's already a match against the request URL, return it.
  if (cachedResponse) {
    return cachedResponse;
  }

  // Otherwise, return a match for a specific URL:
  const urlToMatch = 'https://example.com/data/generic/image.jpg';
  return caches.match(urlToMatch);
};

const imageCachingStrategy = workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({
  cacheName: 'mycache',
  cacheExpiration: {
      maxEntries: 50
  },
  cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]},
  plugins: [{cachedResponseWillBeUsed}]
});


workboxSW.router.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^https://example\.com/data/'),
  imageCachingStrategy
);
```

Comment: What if the url is like example.com/data/{id}/image?screenSize=980, is there possibilities to make this type of url work with above approach?

Comment: I've updated the response to show using a hardcoded URL as the cache key, and to make the regular expression more generic. I don't really understand how the `{id}` portion of the URL comes into play when determining your cache lookup—Should it be taken into account? Should it be ignored?—so you'd have to adjust the code depending on that.

Comment: Yes i have another url which uses dynamic id, now is it possible to do the same as above for that type of url? Like using 'ignoreSearch: true'

Comment: how to verify if this plugin is being apply?

Comment: I included the applied plugins screenshot, but do not see cachedResponseWillBeUsed, am I looking at the right place?

Comment: Hmmm... sorry about that. Could you use the `dev` rather than `prod` build of the `workbox-sw` imported script and see if anything is logged? There might actually be a conflict due to the `cacheExpiration` plugin also implementing `cachedResposneWillBeUsed`.

Comment: Actually i used following url: https://unpkg.com/workbox-sw@0.0.2/build/importScripts/workbox-sw.dev.v0.0.2.js

Comment: Try https://unpkg.com/workbox-sw@2.0.3/build/importScripts/workbox-sw.dev.v2.0.3.js

Answer (score 4):

To build on the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46283973/2124351) answer, [caches.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match) has an option `ignoreSearch`, so we can simply try again with the same url:

```
cachedResponseWillBeUsed = ({cache, request, cachedResponse}) => {
  if (cachedResponse) {
    return cachedResponse;
  }

  // this will match same url/diff query string where the original failed
  return caches.match(request.url, { ignoreSearch: true });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As of v5, building on aw04's answer, the code should read as follows:

```js
const ignoreQueryStringPlugin = {
    cachedResponseWillBeUsed: async({cacheName, request, matchOptions, cachedResponse, event}) => {
        console.log(request.url);
        if (cachedResponse) {
            return cachedResponse;
        }

        // this will match same url/diff query string where the original failed
        return caches.match(request.url, {ignoreSearch: true});
    }
};
```

```js
registerRoute(
    new RegExp('...'),
    new NetworkFirst({
        cacheName: 'cache',
        plugins: [
            ignoreQueryStringPlugin
        ],
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cacheKeyWillBeUsed` simply, modifying the saved cache key to ignore the query at all, and matching for every response to the url with any query.

```
const ignoreQueryStringPlugin = {
 cacheKeyWillBeUsed: async ({request, mode, params, event, state}) => {
  //here you can extract the fix part of the url you want to cache without the query
  curl = new URL(request.url);
  return curl.pathname;

 }
};
```

and add it to the strategy

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/\/(\?.+)?/,new 
 workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
  matchOptions: {
   ignoreSearch: true,
  },
  plugins: [
   ignoreQueryStringPlugin
  ],
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

`ignoreURLParametersMatching` parameter worked for me:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#ignore_url_parameters